# Find the first ement of jQuery('#options\\[n\\]\\[description\\]').val()

Tags: jquery

I have many text inputs with id pattern like below

```
options[1][description]
options[2][description]
options[3][description]
options[n][description]

<input type="text" class="fes-name-value" name="option[1][description]" id="options[1][description]" rows="3" value="Xe đạp không điện">
```

I want to find the 1st input value.

```
jQuery('#options\\[n\\]\\[description\\]').val();
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Your select is like this `<select id="options[1][description]">` ?

Comment: sorry, i means text input. I updated the question.

Comment: Try `$('[id="options[n][description]"]').val();`

Comment: @Andrew Brooke: it does not work. i think n should be a search pattern, but i dont know how to write it :(

Comment: Look at the snippet in my answer, it works

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), since you have brackets in the ID

```
$('[id="options[n][description]"]').val();
```

Here's an example.

```js
$('#output').text($('[id="options[1][description]"]').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="fes-name-value" name="option[1][description]" id="options[1][description]" rows="3" value="Xe đạp không điện">
<div id="output"></div>
```